# Cannot install Tensorflow in Python

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5

I'm running python 3.5.3 on Windows

I tried using

```
pip install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and here's what i get back

```
Using cached tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in 
c:\users\max\miniconda3\lib\site-packages (from tensorflow)
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 
215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 335, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 666, in _prepare_file
    check_dist_requires_python(dist)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\packaging.py", line 48, in check_dist_requires_python
    feed_parser.feed(metadata)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 178, in feed
self._input.push(data)
  File "C:\Users\Max\Miniconda3\lib\email\feedparser.py", line 104, in push
self._partial.write(data)
TypeError: string argument expected, got 'NoneType'
```

I've also tried

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

but I get back

```
'pip3' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I'm not too sure what the error is, and googling hasn't gotten me any results

Comment: This is probably a bug, and better answered if you file an issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues)

Comment: Well, do you have `pip3` defined (added to the `PATH`) ?

Answer (score 3):

I also had the same issue. I'm using Anaconda, and I managed to install it with these commands:

```
conda create -n tensorflow 
activate tensorflow
pip install --ignore-installed --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-1.0.1-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl
```

This worked for me, and probably this will work for miniconda too.